# java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed When join on stream Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have this code

```scala
val counter = event_stream
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "5 minutes")
    .groupBy(
      window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
      $"value")
    .agg(count("value") as "kafka.count",collect_set("topic") as "kafka.topic")
    .drop("window")
    .withColumnRenamed("value","join_id")

    counter.printSchema


  val counter1 = event_stream
    .groupBy("value")
    .count()
//    .agg(count("value") as "kafka.count",collect_set("topic") as "kafka.topic")
    .withColumnRenamed("value","join_id")

  counter1.printSchema()

  val result_stream = event_stream.join(counter,$"value" === $"join_id")
    .drop("key")
    .drop("value")
    .drop("partition")
    .drop("timestamp")
    .drop("join_id")
    .drop("timestampType")
    .drop("offset")
//    .withColumnRenamed("count(value)", "kafka.count")
    .withColumnRenamed("topic","kafka.topic")

  result_stream.printSchema()

  KafkaSink.write(counter, topic_produce)
//  KafkaSink.writeToConsole(result_stream, topic_produce)
```

If I send it to console where I have used Outputmode.Complete it works fine but when I use OutputMode.Append. It gives different errors when sending different streaming queries above.

This is my write function

```scala
private def writeStream(df:DataFrame, topic:String): StreamingQuery = {
    df
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KafkaUtils.kafkaServers)
      .option("topic", topic)
      .option("checkpointLocation", KafkaUtils.checkPointDir)
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
      .start()
  }
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected e.g. {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}, got 1
{"path":"file:///home/ukaleem/Documents/freenet/Proto2/src/main/resource/events-identification-carrier-a.txt","timestamp":1530198790000,"batchId":0}
```

Why do I get this error?

**PART 2: If I do from the above code**

```scala
val result_stream = event_stream.join(counter,$"value" === $"join_id")
 KafkaSink.write(result_stream, topic_produce)
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.OffsetSeq.toStreamProgress(OffsetSeq.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: assertion failed
```

Both cases would work for me. But I'm getting error in both.

**EDIT: I solved the first part. But Still, need the second one.**

Comment: Can you answer your own question with to describe "EDIT: I solved the first part. But Still, need the second one." even if the second question is not solved yet? I would even recommend asking two separate questions and answer the first part as a separate question. WDYT?

Comment: When do you get "java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed"? Does this happen always when you start the app? Do you use any `checkpointLocation` option? Did you change the structured query in-between to use different sources?

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve both. 
What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Sam I resolved the issue please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I faced the same issue. This happens only when I am using existing checkpointLocation. I changed the code and wanted to start the app wherever it left off but spark throws this error. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I resolved both, I'll answer in the evening

Answer (score 5):

The assertion fails due to checkpoint because for every topic there is an offset created so when a new topic is written by writeStream then it tries to assert on the offset but it doesn't find any offset inside checkpoint so AssertionError.
Try this:

```
.option("failOnDataLoss", false) //whether to fail the query when it's possible that data is lost
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a case out there where "failOnDataLoss" alone is not enough to resolve this. Hit this with spark 2.3.0 and then upgraded to spark 2.4.0 and got a much clearer error that the problem arose from [adding a new source to an existing join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880968/spark-structured-streaming-assertionerror-in-checkpoint-due-to-increasing-the). The resolution then was to backup the checkpoint directory and remove it so that it would get created again.